# Discrete - Determining how many times the print statement is being executed.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm quite bad at solving those kind of problems. Could you please guide me how to solve and how to approach the following?

Determine how many times the print statement is executed.

1)

```
   for i:=1 to 20 do
     for j:=1 to i do
       for k:=1 to j do
         if (i-j)(i-k)(j-k) \\not equal to 0, then
           print i * j + k
```

2)

```
  for i:=1 to 20 do
    for j:=1 to i do
      for k:=1 to j do
        if (i-j)(j-k) \\not equal to 0, then
          print i * j + k
```

3)

```
        for i:=1 to 20 do
          for j:=i+1 to 21 do
            for k:=j+1 to 22 do
               print i * j + k
```

Thank you so much, I appreciate all of your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem into smaller, easier to solver parts: First, how many times is the loop running? If nothing else, this will give you some upper bound and might make the problem seem more manageable. Call this total $t$. If you can't find a clever way of doing this, just use brute force and write down each step.

Next, how many times does $i-j=0$? Which is the same as how often does $i=j$? In the first problem you see that $j$ ends at $i$, so no matter what $k$ is doing during that loop, you know the condition $(i-j)=0$ is true, so nothing is being printed. Same thing for $i-k=0$, $j-k=0$, etc. Since you are multiplying $(i-j)(i-k)(j-k)$ you only need one to equal zero. Count all of these occurrences and call them $a_i$. You subtract these numbers from the total, since nothing is being printed.

Then, do any of those occur at the same time: does $i=j$ when $i=k$ or $j=k$? Only consider pairs. Call these numbers $b_i$. You add these numbers back to the total, since you could be over counting in the previous step.

Finally, consider when all three $(i-j)$, $(i-k)$, $(j-k)$ equal zero at the same time. Call this number $c$. You will need to subtract this because you will have added too much in the previous step.

This gives you $t - \sum a_i + \sum b_i - c$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is always the alternative way of solving this, replace the print statement with an accumulator and run the code, isn't this specifically why computers were invented?

`x:=0
for i:=1 to 20 do
  for j:=1 to i do
     for k:=1 to j do
         if (i-j)(j-k)(k-i)
            x := x + 1`

print "1 and 2)",x

As noted by Sal, this loop structure is very inefficient in so far as you end up doing j tests (due to the K loop) * 20 (i loop) where i=j, and therefore will not print.  Also to note in prob #1 K=I only when J=I making the test K=I unnecessary and J=I only at the top of each loop of J, and J=K at the top of the K loop.  More efficient structure would be: 

`1,2) both are identical
for i:=3 to 20 do // Skip i=1,2 because will not print
  for j:=2 to i-1 do // skip j=1,i because will not print
        for k:=1 to j-1 do // skip k=j because will not print
           // print or accumulate X...`

3) as original because no "if" statement to optimize out

Calculates as $$loopCount(prob 1 or 2) = \sum_{i=3}^{20}\sum_{j=2}^{i-1}\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}1$$

$$loopCount(prob 3) = \sum_{i=1}^{20}\sum_{j=i+1}^{21}\sum_{k=j+1}^{22}1$$